# Query where clause based on user input

Tags: html, sql

I have some html that allows the user to search with 2 criteria: name and cost. I am trying to make it so that the query displays results based on what the user enters for name and cost. There are 3 cases: name entered no cost, cost entered no name, both entered

```
SELECT name, cost FROM table WHERE...
```

I know to get the values entered by doing $_POST['name'] and $_POST['cost'] but I am struggling on how to set up the query to display the information based on the possible user input combinations

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you basically want?

```
select . . .
from t
where (name = @name or @name is null) and
      (cost = @cost or @cost is null);
```

Here `@name` and `@cost` are parameters used to pass the user input values into the query.

Comment: Note that getting this to actually work in PHP may require more finessing than this.

Comment: Well if the user only enters a cost then I would need to do where cost = users input. If they only enter a name it is name = user input. Then if they enter both then it's where name = user input for name and cost = user input for cost

Comment: if name and cost are both null, it will return all results. Should you also include another and that is (name is not null and cost is not null). I couldn't add the @'s above in the comment because it thought I was calling out multiple users.

Comment: @Joel there are 3 cases. Name, cost, name and cost.

Comment: @julia, I was trying to point out that the code above in this comment allows a fourth case of "no name" and "no cost" that would return all of the values from t. I wasn't sure you wanted to actually do that so you would need another and that made sure there was at least one input for either cost or name.

Comment: @Joel . . . This will return all rows if both parameters are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I always arrange the SQL like below:-

```
  $nane = $_POST['name']:
  $cost = $_POST['cost'];

    if((isset($nane) && ($nane != "")) && (isset($cost) && ($cost != ""))) 
    {
             $sql = "select name,cost from table where columnNm ='".$nane."' and columnNm1 = ".$cost;
     }
       else if((isset($nane) && ($nane != "")) && (!isset($cost) && ($cost == ""))) 
      {
              $sql = "select name,cost from table where columnNm ='".$nane."'";
      }
       else if((!isset($nane) && ($nane == "")) && (isset($cost) && ($cost != ""))) 
      {
             $sql = "select name,cost from table where columnNm1 = ".$cost;
        }
```

I solve my issues like this. If you think it's suitable for you then you may use it.